# Do you have to use -webkit- syntax anymore?

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm using the flex box technique to layout my webpage, but I have come across with some confusion about the syntax. What I'm confused about is do you have to use -webkit- anymore or has all browsers implemented HTML5 yet. I have been looking for answers on the various websites and one person says you need to use the -webkit- syntax and another person says you don't have to use it anymore. I understand what flex boxes do I'm just confused on whether you need to use -webkit- or not. If I don't can someone show me the correct syntax and if I do need to use the -webkit- syntax can someone show me how to implement my layout into Firefox, Opera, and IE. I know Chrome and Safari use the -webkit- syntax.

```
header, section, footer, article , aside, hgroup, nav {
    display: block;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
}

h1 {
    font: bold 20px tahoma;
}

h2 {
    font: bold 14px tahoma;
}

#page_wrap {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

#top_header {
    background: red;
    border: 4px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#top_menu {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

#top_menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    font: bold 14px tahoma;
}

#section {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
}

#main_section {
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#side_news {
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 220px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #a4a4a4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgb(110,110,110) 10px 10px 10px;
}

#the_footer {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}

article {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

article footer {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been developing a CSS framework, and fromt hat I learned: To make things work for real, you have to also type it all out. That means in short: You should use the -webkit- prefix, and the same settings without. Besides, there is also `-o-` (Opera), `-moz-` (Firefox), `-ms-` and sometimes `-Ms` (IE, and yes, case sensitive). Very rarely there might be also `-khtml-`...but the chance you run into that is equal to zero. I have not seen any modern browser that uses that one any longer.

It might be painful to duplicate your statements, but that is how you make your CSS cross-browser compatible. And that is why I started to use PHP to do it instead...

You can also look up the statements - i.e. `box-pack` - and see their browser compatibility and syntaxes.

For example: Google Chrome seems to preffer -webkit- over the "non-branded" (no -webkit-) version. Safari tends to ignore the branded version and uses the non-branded version.

Comment: I've never heard of -Ms with the capital M.  Where is that used?  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#vendor-keywords

Comment: @dcc: I once looked something up about box-shadow (i think?) and one article suggested using `-Ms-` too. I just adapted it over the time, and used it later in my generator. But really, I can not clearly remember either...

Comment: Checkout the link I posted.  -Ms doesn't exist.  Whereever you found that, they lied to you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hrome seems to preffer -webkit- over the "non-branded" version'? If Chrome supports both prefixed and unprefixed versions of some CSS property and the unprefixed one comes last in the code, there are cases in which Chrome still uses the prefixed one that comes earlier? Can you show any example?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn: In my experience, when I open the element explorer (in the context enu, inspect element) and look at the CSS, it happens that the non-prefixed version has a strike-thru and the prefixed version isn't. So I can disable it, etc. But sometimes its even a bit odd-er... Just look hee, bottom right: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrandao66nmzlly/Screenshot%202014-09-09%2004.21.39.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

You can't ever drop the `-webkit` prefix from `display: -webkit-box`, because the standardized version is *not* called `box`.

Instead, it's called `display:flex`. The associated flexbox properties (including `-webkit-box-pack`) all have different names in the "new" standardized flexbox model, too.

Having said that -- you should prefer the new `display:flex` model to the old `-webkit-box`/`-moz-box` model, because the new version has better interoperability and cross-browser support, because it's actually standardized.

Answer (score 1):

The -webkit- prefix is needed for Safari and Chrome when using transitions, transforms, animation, gradients, calc, flexbox, and columns.  For border-radius, box-shadow, border-image, and text-shadow it's not really necessary unless you want to cover older browsers like Safari 5.0.

Comment: There is no need in `-webkit-` prefix for gradients in Chrome and Safari. Only older Android browsers still need it.