# vertical scrolling not working on mobile firefox it says -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch is invalid property value

Tags: css

I have a web page  works fine on mobile chrome but on mobile firefox vertical scrolling does not work fine it says  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch is invalid property value any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the [prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) `-webkit` specifies properties that are for *webkit* based browsers which Firefox isn't. Also, avoid [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling) properties

Comment: okay then how make it work for firefox?

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit` is a declaration used in CSS to tell browsers supporting -webkit  what to do. That includes but is not limited to:

- Safari
- Chrome
- Opera

Nowadays however, some attributes work without using the `-webkit` declaration, but have a look at this to gain some further insight on the topic:

> [Do you have to use -webkit- syntax anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706551/do-you-have-to-use-webkit-syntax-anymore)

Now, firefox, is not a -webkit based browser. For firefox you should instead use the `-moz-` declaration.

Now, using:

```
-moz-overflow-scrolling:touch
```

WIll not work, because `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is an non-standardised attribute created exclusively for safari on mobile. So if I were you I would delegate the attribute:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
```

To only work on Webkit based browsers:

```
@media print and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .scrolling-page{
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling; touch;
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to suggest an edit that you think would work other than what I just wrote.